# Javascript / JQuery Conditional replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable in javascript:

```
var myvar = "0711111111";
```

I bascially need to do a condition saying:

```
if (myvar's first character = '0') or (myvar's first character = '+') {

then ... replace the first character with 'somethingelse';

}
```

Comment: Make sure you understand the meaning of `=` and `==`/`===` in the first instance. It will save you a lot of time.

Comment: This is a duplicate of _so_ many questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this !

```
var myvar =     "0711111111" , repWithChar  =   "x";
var firstChar   =   myvar.charAt(0);
if ((firstChar === "0") || (firstChar === "+")) {
  console.log( myvar.replace(myvar.charAt(0), repWithChar) );
}
```

Output: x711111111

Answer (score 0):

```
var myvar = "0711111111";

if (myvar.charAt(0) == '0' || myvar.charAt(0) == '+') {
   // Replace the char in pos 0 with desired char (now using '=')
   myvar = myvar.replace(myvar.charAt(0), '=')  

}
```

---

```
Output: "=711111111"
```

Comment: Please specify the reason of down votes, this code works, and it's what user asked for

Comment: I didn't downvote, but using array syntax on strings doesn't work in older IE (which may or may not matter). Also, why use `[0]` in the `if` condition and `.charAt(0)` in the next line?

Comment: You're right, I updated the answer to use only `.charAt()` function

Comment: Why use functions for doing this easy substitution? http://jsperf.com/questions-27226888

Comment: 2 downvotes, awesome hahahah ! @TheGr8_Nik I think this is the best way for a beginner to understand it

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik if you do `myvar[0] = '='` won't work fine in all the browsers. For example, IE will fail as @nnnnnn said

Comment: @Liarez - yes, ie 7 and older... I think that I baginner should understand that a `String` is only an `Array of character`

Comment: I supose you learn that the first programming class day and compatibility were more important

Comment: @Liarez - we are speaking about ie7 support... But `myvar[0] = '='` was wrong, we can't edit a `string` in javascript, we must build a new one (I learned something new). If you store the first char in a variable instead to call the `charAt` three times I will remove the -1 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myvar = "0711111111";

if(myvar[0] == "0" || myvar[0] == "+"){

    myvar = myvar.substring(1);

}
```

or Use `charAt()`

```
  if(myvar.charAt(0) == "0" || myvar.charAt(0) == "+"){

        myvar = myvar.substring(1);

    }
```

or use `substring()`

```
 if(myvar.substring(0,1) == "0" || myvar.substring(0,1) == "+"){

            myvar = myvar.substring(1);

   }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ubynje65/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myvar = "0711111111";

if(myvar[0] == "0" || myvar[0] == "+"){

    myvar[0] = "$"; // U can replace

}
```

Answer (score -1):

take the first character with `myvar[0]` and compare with the other two characters

```
var firstchar = myvar[0]; //or myvar.charAt(0) for ie7 and older support

if ( firstchar === '0' || firstchar === '+' ) {
    // do stuff
    myvar = myvar.replace( firstchar, 'X' ); // where X is the new character
}
```

Comment: This is a really bad answer.

Comment: @Andy - why is a bad answer?

Comment: Your first attempt at answering the question before you copied everyone else was a rubbish answer.

Comment: This only covers half of the question. How do you replace the first character in the string if the if condition is met?